# How to get AutoRefreshingAuthClient from AuthClient without any service account (Google Auth)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-sheets, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I need an **AutoRefreshingAuthClient** to use [gsheet](https://pub.dev/packages/gsheets) to play with authenticated users Google Sheet. I can get **AuthClient** using [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) package.

So, How can I get **AutoRefreshingAuthClient** from **AuthClient** in a flutter application without any service account?

The reason I don't want to use a Service Account is,
If I use a Service Account, all files are saved into this Service Account. But, I want to read, write and use Google Sheet from the authenticated user's account.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this? I have the same exact issue

Comment: Hi, I am also having the same kind of requirement, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [googleapis](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis) instead. Seems like [gsheets](https://pub.dev/packages/gsheets) was made to work **specifically** with Service Accounts so even if you create a valid AutoRefreshingAuthClient it'll check to see if it's a Service Account.

Here's how I did it with the SheetsApi (*The `GoogleAuthClient` class was found after a lot of searching on GitHub and multiple users had the same thing*):

```
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    
    class GoogleAuthClient extends http.BaseClient {
      final Map<String, String> _headers;
    
      final http.Client _client = new http.Client();
    
      GoogleAuthClient(this._headers);
    
      Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) {
        return _client.send(request..headers.addAll(_headers));
      }
    }
    
    final client = GoogleAuthClient((await _googleSignIn.currentUser.authHeaders));
    
    _SheetApi = sheets.SheetsApi(client);
```

There is as decent amount of overhead on our side with SheetsApi compared to GSheets. Like appending rows or simply naming your Spreadsheet requires more lines of code and/or objects:

```
    // Sheet creation
    sheets.Spreadsheet request = sheets.Spreadsheet.fromJson({
    'properties': {
        'title': "$title",
      },
    });
    sheets.Spreadsheet sh =  getSheetApi().spreadsheets.create(request));
    
    // Add first row
    List<String> row = [...];
    getSheetApi().spreadsheets.values.append(createSheetRows([columns]), sh.spreadsheetId, "Sheet1!$startLetter:$endLetter",
              valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED');

...

 static sheets.ValueRange createSheetRows(List<List<String>> row){
    return sheets.ValueRange.fromJson({
      "values": row,
      "majorDimension": "ROWS"
    });
 }

 static sheets.ValueRange createSheetRow(List<String> row){
    return createSheetRows([row]);
 }
```